# Why am I getting a 'subscript out of bounds' error when using getElementText() with RSelenium using Docker?

Tags: r, getelementbyid, rselenium

I am using docker with `RSelenium` to pull text from dropdown menus on a website using code that worked last year, but this time I am getting the error:

> "Error in resContent[["status"]] : subscript out of bounds"

when trying to use `getElementText()`. I have searched online and can't seem to run across anyone with the same problem. Reproducible example below:

```
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)

eCaps <- list(chromeOptions = list(
  args = c("--window-size=1920,1080",
           "--disable-extensions",
           "--proxy-server='direct://'",
           "--proxy-bypass-list=*",
           "--start-maximized",
           "--headless",
           "--desable-gpu",
           "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
           "--no-sandbox",
           "--ignore-certificate-errors"
  ),
  prefs = list("profile.default_content_settings.popups" = 0L,
               "download.prompt_for_download" = FALSE)
))

shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "chrome",
                      extraCapabilities = eCaps)
remDr$open()

remDr$navigate("https://demoqa.com/select-menu")
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)

WebElem <- remDr$findElement("id", "oldSelectMenu")
WebElemText <- WebElem$getElementText()
```